# Where to find token on token based authentication

Tags: authentication, token, http-token-authentication

I was trying to find the token on a login page. I've already searched on page source but it'isnt here. I'd like to know the practices for passing an access token and then the way to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for token authentication is to pass it along with the request headers.
Normally u can find the tokens in the cookies with the respective key name

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood you. I know sometimes it is inserted on an input hidden, but in this case it isn't. What do you mean is the post request shown on "Inspect element"?

Comment: The token is not stored in the html. It is stored in browser storages such as cookies or local storage

Comment: When you click on inspect element, navigate to application in the open window, there you can find these

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have been really helpful